# Database Spinner and Brackets

Tags: android, database, spinner

I load a Database into a Spinner.

This Spinner shows the entries of the Database: [a][b][c]

Why are there brackets? And how can I delete them properly?  In this moment I delete them with:

```
spinner.replace("[","");
spinner.replace("]","");
```

I hope there is a better solution.